# Python - Plot a matplotlib histogram with 2 conditions on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, conditional-statements, histogram

I m trying to plot an histogram with two conditions on the data because it presents some noise and i would like to neglict value inferior to 5 and superior to 100, so when i plot i try with : "data[data> 5. and data< 100.]"
But it doesnt work...
I obtain this error message : "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

Elements = open("C:/.../Desktop/test.txt","r")
data= np.genfromtxt(Elements,skip_header=0) 
Elements.close()

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(7, 5.3)


num_bins = 75
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data[data> 5. and data< 100.]*1.78,num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Feret',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('frequency',fontsize=18)
plt.xlim(0.,50.)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)
# plt.title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')
plt.savefig('Hist_GS_ext.png', dpi=1000)

# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15,bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try to do some exploration yourself next time: what exactly is your problem. Here for example it doesn't have anything to do with 95% or your code: it is just logical indexing of the numpy array. Your question code could be literally 3 lines long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do element-wise logical AND, but use the wrong syntax. Use `&` instead of `and`, and encapsulate individual expressions into parentheses:

```
 data[(data>5.) & (data<100.)]
```

Another way to do the same is to use `numpy` function `logical_and`:

```
data[np.logical_and(data>5., data<100.)]
```